# Spring не видит resource file

Tags: spring, resources

в springe не могу работать с JPA так как он не видит мой resource file.

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="aoz_jdbc" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/aoc</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

aplication-context.xml файл

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties" ref="eclipselinkjpavendoradapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.andrew</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bibabotan"/>
        <property name="username" value="aoz_root"/>
        <property name="password" value="123456"/>
    </bean>
```

в Java вызываю так

```
@ImportResource("classpath*:/spring-conf/spring-config.xml")
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "aoz_jdbc")
    private EntityManager em;
```

Exception

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'aoz_jdbc' is defined:org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No bean named 'aoz_jdbc' is defined
```

Comment: А можете показать ещё структуру файлов и папок в проекте? Это у вас Spring MVC или Boot?